# Can't get GETTEXT to work with PHP on MAMP server and Windows 10

Tags: php, mamp, gettext, poedit

I want to use `gettext` and `poedit` with `php` for website translation. I can get `poedit` to work but `gettext` does not seem to work in my local web dev environment `MAMP`, at least I think that is the problem.

My specs:

```
OS: Windows 10
Gettext 0.21 with Libiconv 1.16 (installed with executable)
Dev Server: MAMP 4.2 (both apache and nginx server show the same error)
Dev Environment: PhpStorm (with MAMP local server set up)
PHP: 7.4 or 8.0 (both throw error)
Browser: Chrome and Firefox (both throw error)
```

MWE HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><?php gettext("Welcome") ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gettext() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\test\test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\test\test.php on line 8
```

[image]

I have reinstalled `MAMP` and updated `gettext` but the error persists. Am I missing something?

It would also interest me how you guys do translation professionally. `Poedit` is very convenient but is there an even better approach? So far I've only seen `PHP` or `Laravel` arrays, which are very unpleasant to work with, when you have large `paragraphs` with `spans`.

**Edit:**

Running `phpinfo()` shows `gettext`:

In **Environment**:
[image]
[image]

In **PHP Variables**:
[image]
[image]

**Edit2:**

`php_gettext.dll` can be found in `php/ext` dir and `extention=gettext` is activated in the `php.ini`.

Running `php -r "echo gettext('hello');"` in the `php` dir produces:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: C:\php\ext\gettext (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden), C:\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: C:\php\ext\gettext (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden), C:\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gettext() in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gettext() in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1
```

I've extracted the `extension_dir` from `php -i` which is `C:PHP/ext`. This dir did not exist before. I've tested it by just moving `C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\lib\gettext` inside there but no change. The gettext folder had no `.so` files in it, unlike what @cetver's answer said. After that I tried moving my whole PHP dist to `C:PHP` but this didn't change anything either.

Short: I moved gettext to the `php extension dir` but it didn't help.

**Edit3:**

Now I restarted my machine and it works!

`phpinfo()` shows `gettext` now and the site loads:

[image]

**Take away**:

Use `C:PHP` for your `PHP` dist.

Comment: Run a page with `<?php phpinfo();` there and see if gettext module is actually there.

Comment: @LazyOne I've added it in the edit section.

Comment: Well .. your PHP shows error .. so it clearly does not know about it (the actual function). 1) Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#122509 -- try using `_()`  function  2) Restart PC -- perhaps your PHP still does not have the actual module loaded. Because I would expect to see a separate Gettext section with PHP module for GETTEXT (sorry; not using it myself so cannot test here .. but I do see a separate module when I check PHP config on GoDaddy shared hosting for example)

Comment: None of the two outputs really demonstrates that the `gettext` extension is actually loaded. I'd use `php -m` on the commandline, though you might have different configurations for webserver and CLI SAPIs. For further inspection, I'd turn to `php -i`.

Comment: Not sure of what `C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv` contains, but gettext is a standalone PHP extension, it doesn't need the gettext command-line programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gettext` extensions loaded for CLI SAPI:

`$ php -r "echo gettext('hello');"`

Web SAPI haven't it: search on the phpinfo page compile flag `--with-gettext[=DIR]`

1. Find extension dir: `php -i | grep extension_dir` (example extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20190902 => /usr/lib/php/20190902
   )
2. Find the gettext extension path: `find /usr/lib/php/20190902 | grep gettext` (example /usr/lib/php/20190902/gettext.so)
3. copy extension from cli dir to web dir: `cp /usr/lib/php/20190902/gettext.so <phpinfo_page>/extension_dir_path`
4. reload web server

Comment: I've tried doing what you proposed. Please see **Edit2** section.